# How add Evil keybindings to Magit, without removing all Magit prefix-keys

Tags: key-bindings, magit, evil, transients

In magit status of a Git repository, you usually press `f u` to fetch from upstream (these keybindings in Magit will call `magit-fetch-from-upstream`).

With Magit keybindings I have noticed the letters `hkjl` after prefix `f` were not used yet. So I added the following:

```
(map! :map magit-mode-map
 :n "fh" #'evil-window-left
 :n "fl" #'evil-window-right)
```

This works well in Magit. Later it turns out this also disabled the prefix-related keybinding `u` after prefix `f`. So I'm wondering how I could add another keybinding after prefix `f` while  retaining the other Magit prefix-related keybindings?

Comment: Please always mention if you are using the doom Emacs distribution. Others have no idea what the `map!` syntax means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transients activate their own keymaps. The [Modifying Existing Transients](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/transient.html#Modifying-Existing-Transients) section of the transient manual describes how to extend existing transients. Unfortunately, it generally takes quite some investment to understand the transient manual.

Anyway, you could extend the 'magit-fetch prefix as follows:

```lisp
(with-eval-after-load 'magit-fetch
  (transient-append-suffix
  'magit-fetch
  '(3)
  ["Navigate"
   ("h" "forward char" evil-backward-char :transient t)
   ("l" "backward char" evil-forward-char :transient t)]))
```

The second argument `(3)` defines [where to add the extra commands](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/transient.html#Modifying-Existing-Transients).

The `:transient t` sets the transient to [stay transient](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/transient.html#Transient-State).

I am not sure how to 'point' Emacs to use the 'original' keymap if some key is not included in the prefix (I vaguely remember this was possible, but I can not find it again now... however, maybe I have dreamed it :).

Comment: Your message is appreciated, it took time to wrap my head around what transients are and how it works. Unfortunately, as you provided didn't worked. I copied it and got this error: `Error caused by user's config or system: [path to keybinding], (error magit-fetch is not a transient command)`. When I do <kbd>C-h k</h> <kbd>f</kbd> in Magit status window, he is waiting for second input so I can't find it. Based on docs about transients, I found this section: https://magit.vc/manual/0.1.0/transient/Modifying-Existing-Transients.html but it didn't solved my question yet.

Comment: The `magit-fetch` command is not known before magit-fetch.el has been loaded. I have updated the answer with a solution.

Comment: Whoa, it worked straight now! Now it makes much more sense. I really deeply appreciate your response. Learning about transient, I'm going to apply in my other magit workflows as well. Thank you for your help ☺️!